# Translate Java "for" loop to python

Tags: java, python

I am trying to program Quicksort algorithm in python from the code I have in Java, but I am having trouble with this particular line:

```
int partition(int start, int fin, int[] A){
    int piv = fin;
    int rightside = start;
    for (int i = 0; start<= (fin-1); i++){
        if(A[i]<A[piv]){
            swap(A, i, rightside);
            rightside++;
        } 
    }
    swap(A, piv, rightside);           
    return rightside;
}
```

The "for" statement on python is a bit complicated to understand, how can I translate `for (int i = 0; start<= (fin-1); i++){` into a python for?

Comment: It's a "for each" loop. Similar to java's `for(MyObject obj: container){..}`

Comment: Something like `for i in xrange(0, fin):`

Comment: My advice would be *not* to do direct "transliterations" from Java to Python.  Instead, I would look at quicksort implementations done in Python and try to understand the techniques used by them. [Here's a quick example](https://gist.github.com/juanarrivillaga/6ef6deef3d2ab627eb882c9460de80b2) of how you would implement a simple quicksort in python.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a direct translation of your code (it would work if you were updating fin in the loop:

```
i = 0
while start <= (fin-1):
 i+=1
```

Otherwise, use `range` or `xrange` as:

```
for i in xrange(0, fin)
```

Comment: While that works, it's not very pythonic.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote, but just a heads up, but this is going to attract downvotes because one does not generally write `while` loops in this case in Python, and it is actually an anti-pattern because they are much less performant than equivalent for-loops.

Comment: The question was asking how to write that `for` in Python. I added an explanation to my answer.